# Residual bound in LU factorization

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, matrix-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

I was trying to understand why LU factorization is more numerically stable than the method of inverting A directly. [This answer talks about it.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1975610/why-is-solving-linear-equation-more-stable-than-directly-computing-matrix-invers) It says the below:

$$
\begin{array}{l}{\text { If } x \text { is computed by LU factorization, the residual can be bounded by }} \\ {\qquad\|b-A x\| \leq c u\|L\| U\|\| x \|}\end{array}
$$
Can someone show a step-by-step way of proving this result?

I referred the textbook "Accuracy and Stability of Numerical Algorithms" by Nicholas J Higham , but I was not able to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof can be based on the following facts (see Theorems 9.3 and 9.4 in the first edition of the referenced book):

> **Fact 1**
>   Let $T\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a nonsingular triangular matrix (upper or lower). Then the computed solution $\hat{x}$ of $Tx=b$ satisfies
>   $$
> (T+\Delta T)\hat{x}=b, \quad |\Delta T|\leq nu|T|+O(u^2).
> $$
>
> **Fact 2**
>   Computed LU factors $\hat{L}$ and $\hat{U}$ of $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ satisfy
>   $$
> \hat{L}\hat{U}=A+\Delta A, \quad |\Delta A|\leq nu|\hat{L}||\hat{U}|+O(u^2).
> $$
>   Here the inequalities are understood component-wise.

We start by computing the LU factorization to obtain $\hat{L}$ and $\hat{U}$. Then we obtain $\hat{y}$ by solving $\hat{L}y=b$ such that
$$
(\hat{L}+\Delta L)\hat{y}=b,\quad|\Delta L|\leq nu|\hat{L}|+O(u^2),
$$
and $\hat{x}$ by solving $\hat{U}x=y$ such that
$$
(\hat{U}+\Delta U)\hat{x}=\hat{y},\quad |\Delta U|\leq nu|\hat{U}|+O(u^2).
$$
At the end, we have
$$
(\hat{L}+\Delta L)(\hat{U}+\Delta U)\hat{x}=b.
$$
Now for the residual, we get
$$
\begin{split}
b-A\hat{x}
&=(\hat{L}+\Delta L)(\hat{U}+\Delta U)\hat{x}-(\hat{L}\hat{U}-\Delta A)\hat{x}
\\&=(\Delta L\hat{U}+\hat{L}\Delta U+\Delta L\Delta U+\Delta A)\hat{x}=: E\hat{x},
\end{split}
$$
where
$$
|E|\leq|\Delta L||\hat{U}|+|\hat{L}||\Delta U|+|\Delta A|+|\Delta L||\Delta U|
\leq 3nu|\hat{L}||\hat{U}|+O(u^2).
$$
We absorbed $|\Delta L||\Delta U|$ in the higher order term $O(u^2)$.